# Electrical resistivity

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, lattices

I have read that in non-metals solids the electric resistivity is reduced if we increase temperature.But this isn't logical.I mean if temperature is increased ok the electrons get extra energy but as well the vibration of the atoms is increased so electric resistivy is increased.Temperatures cant make electrons overcome the band gap easily.There should be an increase till the temperature is high enough so with little energy the valence electrons would get ionized and then electric resistivity to be dicreased. Where am I wrong?Help appreciated

Comment: You are right. But till the temperature is that high, there should be an increase, and so it is.

Comment: Yeah but why tables show a negative temperature coefficient of resistivity for some materials then?

Comment: Well, just like that: as T grows, more electrons make it across the band gap, hence more charge carriers, hence more conductivity, even though the situation for each particular electron grows worse.

Comment: What you write doesnt make any sense . 1 hour ago you said that the resistivity is increased

Comment: Then I might have misunderstood your original post, sorry about that. No, it is the conductivity that increases, and I just explained why.

Comment: Wait so not all electrons have the same energy or absorb the same energy? What is happening?

Comment: Of course not. Wait, didn't you use the term "band gap" a while before? What is that gap and why is it important? I'll tell you why: most electrons just sit below the gap and do not matter. But a few of them have energies that put them above the gap. They are allowed to roam freely around the crystal, hence the conductivity.

Comment: Well band gap is the energy required for a  valence electron to leave its orbital and enter the conduction band.Non-metals usually have a relative medium band gap.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, and that's pretty much what I just said, isn't it?

Comment: They must have this energy to overcome the band gap . If one valence electron has the energy to overcome this energy barrier then all valence electrons of similar atoms will overcome this energy barrier.

Comment: There is no such thing as few of valence electrons  will pass the energy barriers and some wont.

Comment: I appreciate your contribution despite you having not answered my question yet.

Comment: OK, I got it. You think that since all atoms are identical (which they are), all their orbitals are identical, and so the electrons that reside on these orbitals must have the same energy. Well, that's about right, and that's why once an electron receives a handful of energy from whatever source, it _ceases to occupy that orbital_.

Comment: Yes all atoms of the same element are identical , aren't they?

Comment: They are, but look again at my previous comment.

Comment: Yes I mean there should be a huge change in resistivity if valence electrons have found the energy to overcome the band gap: and before the valence electrons get that energy the resistivity is increased.

Comment: OK, now look at it this way: there is no "before". As soon as the temperature is above 0 K, some electrons (maybe very few) are above the gap. Say, at a given temperature about $1\over 1\,000\,000\,000$ of all electrons get enough energy to overcome the gap; that may seem like not much, but give it a little heat, and you'll find 10 times that much, which is still not much, but hey, it's a 10 times increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between 273 K and 500 K the intrinsic carrier concentration in Si increases by about 5 orders of magnitude. Compare with the decrease in conductivity of a metal over that range. Increase in carriers far outweighs the increased scattering of carriers.